# Multi-dimensional Stern-Brocot tree

Tags: number-theory

I am looking for a multidimensional extension of the Stern-Brocot tree.
Any pointers?

Thanks,

-Arrigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This paper addresses the question:

https://www.academia.edu/70541746/The_n_dimensional_Stern_Brocot_tree